# open a modal window onclick of a cell in calendar and load the url into the modal window

Tags: jquery, html

```
html += "<div class='fc-day-number' onmousedown='modelWinodw()'>" 
        + date.getDate() 
        + "</div>";
```

I want to write a jquery function modelWindow() which opens a modal winodw on click and loads the url mentioned in it.  how to do it ?

Comment: html += "<div class='fc-day-number' onmousedown='modelWindow()'>" + date.getDate() + "</div>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the modal :
http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/Ltcuqpkz/6/

1. Call modalWindow() with url to load.
2. Create modal window and add `<iframe>` in it with the `src` as the url passed.
3. Display the modal.

Here's the sample :

```
function modelWindow(page) {
    var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="text-align:center;"></div>')
        .html('<iframe src="' + page + '" />')
        .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        title: "Modal Window",
        open: function () {
            jQuery('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            });
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was trying to put some styling to the model Window i.e to apply the class from css. How to do it ?